# Correct use of htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities()

Tags: php, security

If I'd have security as first priority, which function should I choose between `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`, and which flags should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, security for what? That's the key question. If by chance you are talking about database then neither are important. It all depends on what you want to secure